# How do I use an image for a button instead of standard input type button?

Tags: html, image, button

I have this code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert('A message here');" value="Button"/>
```

How do I use my own image-button instead of the standard button?

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="{{your image url here}}" onclick="alert('A message here');" />
```

or

```
<div onclick="alert('A message here');" style="background: url({{your image url here}});background-repeat:no-repeat; width:150px; height:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `<button>` tag instead of an `<input type="button">`, you can fill it with HTML content:

```
<button onclick="alert('A message here');" type="button">
  <img src="myurl">
</button>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Example: http://jsbin.com/ezeFaYU/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an image button per se but since you're using javascript you can add the click event to an image. See the fiddle below.

```
<img class="button" src="http://goo.gl/UGQl0i" width="100" height="100" onclick="alert('A message here');" >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CN8Js/

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just replace "img.png" with your image.

```
<img src = "img.png" onclick="alert('A message here');"/>
```